# An inequality for nine variables subject to $p\in (0, 1)$, $a_1\leq a_2\leq a_4 , a_1\leq a_3\leq a_4, b_1\leq b_2\leq b_4 , b_1\leq b_3\leq b_4 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

$a_1  , a_2,  a_3 ,  a_4 ,  b_1 ,  b_2 ,  b_3 ,  b_4\in\Bbb R ,  p\in(0, 1)$.
$a_1\leq a_2\leq a_4 ,  a_1\leq a_3\leq a_4 ,  b_1\leq b_2\leq b_4 , b_1\leq b_3\leq b_4 $.

Show that
$$   a_1b_1(1-p)^2+(a_2b_2+a_3b_3)p(1-p)+a_4b_4p^2 $$
$$\geq\big[a_1(1-p)^2+(a_2+a_3)p(1-p)+a_4p^2\big]\big[b_1(1-p)^2+(b_2+b_3)p(1-p)+b_4p^2\big]$$

---

I want to show that LHS- RHS $\geq0$. But

LHS- RHS = $ p(1-p)[(-a_1+a_2+a_3-a_4)(-b_1+b_2+b_3-b_4)p^2+...]$

It's difficult to move forward.

Thank you very much

Comment: Are you sure this is true? Where did it come from? If the a's are 1,2,3,5 and the b's are 1,2,3,3.1 then your product for LHS-RHS is negative.

Comment: @martycohen $p(1-p)(-0.9p^2-0.6p+5)\geq0$

Answer (score 1):

There is a mechanical process to solve the question, however it's so tedious that I never finish the whole process. (tscjlt99 solved it by Mathematica 8.0)
We do some substitutions as follows:

$a_2=a_1+sx$,$a_3=a_1+tx$,$a_4=a_1+x$

$b_2=b_1+qy$,$b_3=b_1+ry$,$b_4=a_1+y$, where $0\leq p,q,r,s,t\leq 1$ and $x,y\geq 0$

Then $LHS-RHS=p(1-p)G(p,q,r,s,t)xy\geq0\Leftrightarrow G(p,q,r,s,t)\geq 0$, where

$G(p,q,r,s,t)=(p+p^2-p^2q-p^2r-p^2s+qs-pqs+p^2qs-prs+p^2rs-p^2t-pqt+p^2qt+rt-prt+p^2rt)$

$$\frac{\partial G}{\partial i}=0$$, where $i=p,q,r,s,t$

The solution is $(p,q,r,s,t)=(1/2,1/2,1/2,1/2,1/2)$

From $G(1/2,1/2,1/2,1/2,1/2)=1/2>0$, we only need to prove the following ten inequalties to finish the proof. 
$G(1,q,r,s,t)\geq 0$,
$G(p,1,r,s,t)\geq 0$,
$G(p,q,1,s,t)\geq 0$,
$G(p,q,r,1,t)\geq 0$,
$G(p,q,r,s,1)\geq 0$,
$G(0,q,r,s,t)\geq 0$,
$G(p,0,r,s,t)\geq 0$,
$G(p,q,0,s,t)\geq 0$,
$G(p,q,r,0,t)\geq 0$,
$G(p,q,r,s,0)\geq 0$.

The question is degraded from **1 inequality with five variables** to **10 inequalities with four variable**. Probably, these ten inequalities are very simple to prove, if not, We can proceed this process until the question is degraded to inequalities with only 1 variable.

**Attachment:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

We have
\begin{align*}
 \mathrm{LHS} - \mathrm{RHS} &= (a_4 - a_2)(b_4 - b_2)p^3(1-p) \\
 &\qquad + (a_4 - a_3)(b_4 - b_3)p^3(1-p)\\
 &\qquad + (a_2 - a_1)(b_2 - b_1)p(1-p)^3\\
 &\qquad + (a_3 - a_1)(b_3 - b_1)p(1 - p)^3\\
 &\qquad + \Big[(a_4 - a_1)(b_4 - b_1) + (a_2 - a_3)(b_2 - b_3)\Big]p^2(1-p)^2\\
 &\ge 0
\end{align*}
where we use $|a_2 - a_3| \le a_4 - a_1$ and $|b_2 - b_3| \le b_4 - b_1$.

We are done.